# Simplifying $(A^c\setminus B^c)^c\cap (A\cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we simplify the following set-theoretical expression?

$$(A^c\setminus B^c)^c\cap (A\cup B)$$

Where $A, B\neq \emptyset$ and $A, B\subset E$.

Let $x\in (A^c\setminus B^c)^c\cap (A\cup B)$, so $x\in (A^c\setminus B^c)^c$ and $x\in (A\cup B)$.

$$(A^c\setminus B^c)^c = (A^c\cap B)^c$$

Therefore $x\notin A^c, B$, and so $x\in A, B^c$. Thus,

$$(A^c\setminus B^c)^c\cap (A\cup B) = A\cap B^c$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some error in your solution.

$$\begin{align*} 
& x \in(A^c \, \backslash \,B^c)^c \cap (A \cup B) \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\,\, & x \notin(A^c \, \backslash \,B^c) \,\, \land \,\, (x \in A \,\, \lor \,\, x \in B) \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\,\, & (x \notin A^c \,\, \lor \,\, x \in B^c) \,\, \land \,\, (x \in A \,\, \lor \,\, x \in B) \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\,\, & (x \in A \,\, \lor \,\, x \notin B) \,\, \land \,\, (x \in A \,\, \lor \,\, x \in B) \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\,\, &  x \in A \\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $$(A^c \, \backslash \,B^c)^c \cap (A \cup B) = A$$